# Loading template tag variables for use in template

Tags: django, django-tagging

How do I load the results of a templatetag into a a template to iterate over? Basically I am aiming to load the tags on a model object (using django-tagging) and then iterate through the tags to create a list of related products based on those tags. Then I would like to iterate through those product objects to display more information about them.

Ex, my template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_rel_from_tag(tag_list):
   try:
       relproducts = UniPart.objects.filter(part__contains = partbase)
    except:
       print "no related products"
       return None
   else:
       relproducts = UniPart.objects.filter(part__contains = partbase)
       return relproducts
```

How do I make it so that `relproducts` is returned as a variable? This is how I call it in the template:

`{% tags_for_object design as tag_list %}`
`{% get_rel_from_tag tag_list %}`

Basically now I want to iterate over relatedprod now but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simple_tag` helper does not allow you to assign the result to a context variable in this way. Try using [`assignment_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the template tag file using `{% load 'your_file_name %}`

Update:Try using 'with' to cache the result from tags_for_object_design

```
{% with tag_list=tags_for_object design %}
```

Comment: Yes it's in the same file as the `tags_for_object` template tag which is working fine and returned `tag_list` properly.